play-pac4j / play framework 3.0 / scala 3 incompatibility
Using scala 3 on the new play 3.x framework, play-pac4j has an issue loading the security filter:
     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: void play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter.$init$(play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter)
     org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter.\<init\>(SecurityFilter.scala:63) 
     org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter$$FastClassByGuice$$11d1583.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE(\<generated\>) 
     org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter$$FastClassByGuice$$11d1583.apply(\<generated\>) 

I have seen this issue when upgrading my project and also using the play-pac4j-java-demo project
You can re-create by setting:
in the build.sbt:
scalaVersion := "3.3.3"
val playPac4jVersion = "12.0.0-PLAY3.0"

in the plugins.sbt:
addSbtPlugin("org.playframework" % "sbt-plugin" % "3.0.1")


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78481774/play-3-pac4j-with-scala-3-server-not-start-up

@Chet You might take a look at this comment from mkurz https://github.com/orgs/playframework/discussions/12867
